# Read Large Text file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I want to get each line from a text file in Python ( around 1 billion lines) and from each line I am taking some words and inserting in another file
I have used

```
with open('') as f:
   for line in f:
       process_line(line)
```

This process is taking a lot of time, How can I process this to read all the contents in about 2 hours ?

Comment: What does `process_line` actually do? Please show us the code.

Comment: its not exactly process_lines. Each line consists of "word,word1,word2" I 'm splitting these three words (.split(",")) and writing them to 3 separate files using f.write()

Comment: If processing each line is independent, this problem can be modelled under divide and conquer. First split the large file into smaller files using Linux split command. Later, run the same program on the split files, preferably in parallel.

Answer (score 3):

The bottleneck of the performance of your script likely comes from the fact that it is writing to 3 files at the same time, causing massive fragmentation between the files and hence lots of overhead.

So instead of writing to 3 files at the same time as you read through the lines, you can buffer up a million lines (which should take less than 1GB of memory), before you write the 3 million words to the output files one file at a time, so that it will produce much less file fragmentation:

```
def write_words(words, *files):
    for i, file in enumerate(files):
        for word in words:
            file.write(word[i] + '\n')

words = []
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f, open('words1.txt', 'w') as out1, open('words2.txt', 'w') as out2, open('words3.txt', 'w') as out3:
    for count, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        words.append(line.rstrip().split(','))
        if count % 1000000 == 0:
            write_words(words, out1, out2, out3)
            words = []
    write_words(words, out1, out2, out3)
```

Comment: Still, 2 *hours* sounds *massively* too long, even for a billion lines. OP's machine may be from the 1970s though.

Comment: I am using latest Macbook Pro ( 8 GB RAM + 512 GB mem)

Comment: I think this is going to take way more than 1 gb, especially since you never clear the `words` list.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oops I meant to but forgot. Fixed then. Thanks.

Comment: But still, quick and dirty calculation, you are materializing a list of `10_000_000` lists (each with three items). *even ignoring the actual strings*, and assuming a list of 3 items is about 88 bytes (again, ignoring the actual strings, which are not trivial), I predict `10_000_000*8*88*1e-9 == 7.04` gigabytes .... take this down by an order of magnitude

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Good point. I've updated the answer to buffer only a million lines at a time then.

Comment: Note, more realistically, I'm still predicting about 2-gigs, given an average string size of about 10, so about 60 bytes per string object, so: `1_000_000*8*(88 + 60*3)*1e-9` but this should be a good size

Answer (score 1):

read about generators in Python.
Yours code should look like this:

```
def read_file(yours_file):
    while True:
        data = yours_file.readline()
        if not data:
            break
        yield data
```